# How to mount an S3 compatible object storage to use it with jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, object-storage, s3fs

I have 2 TB of data on a S3 compatible object storage. I used to keep that data in aws s3 and mount the bucket to my ec2 instance with s3fs. Now I need to use the S3 compatible storage provided my institution, and when I try to mount the bucket to my pc (OSX) with this command:

`s3fs mybucket /mnt/test-bucket -o url=<url>  -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs  -o use_path_request_style`

The command completes, but when I try to cd into the mounted directory, the pc crashes, and I need to reboot. My goal is to start a jupyter notebook container with the mounted bucket volume. What can be the problem? Is there an alternative way use the bucket with jupyter notebook without mounting it?

Comment: Please note that Amazon S3 is a **block storage system**. It is not intended to be 'mounted'. Many modern libraries understand how to use S3 directly (rather than as a 'drive'), so you might consider avoiding `s3fs`. You don't mention how you intend to use the data, but look at things like [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) and S3 capabilities inbuilt into Spark.